# Why is my accept rate zero?

Tags: support, accept-rate

Even though I accepted an answer the accept rate is displayed as zero. Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

The accept rate is only updated periodically, I believe - if you've accepted an answer *just now* then wait a while and it should update.

Also if you accept a CW answer, I don't *believe* that affects anything.

If you could let us now which account you're talking about, that would help :)

EDIT: Okay, having looked into it a bit more, and [found the original blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/) I think the problem is that the questions are too new.

You've only accepted answers to the *new* questions - whereas only questions 3 days old (or older) count for either acceptance or non-acceptance.

Comment: And you need to have asked a minimum number of non-CW questions too

Comment: @ChrisF: That definitely isn't a problem, otherwise the accept rate wouldn't have come up to start with.

Comment: Ah - of course.

Comment: @Skeet Alright then, why do you have a sock puppet?

Comment: @random: See the comments in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8634/what-will-jon-skeet-present-in-stackoverflow-devdays-in-london-cambridge/8639#8639